# Is it possible to Use a Url.Action in razor view with GUID instead of INT

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using the following:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPicture", "Home", new {id = Model.ID})" alt="Member Picture" />
```

This doesn't work because Model.ID is a GUID. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What do you mean on it doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Guids should work in urls and in your controller parameters too.

Comment: Nemesv, you're right. It does work with a Guid. My mistake was in the GetPicture method. I owe everyone an apology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the guid to the controller, but you have to recieve a string as id parameter instead of int.

Razor view:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPicture", "Home", new {id = Model.ID})" alt="Member Picture" />
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetPicture(string id){
        //do magic
    }
```

Comment: The model binder binds also Guids: so `GetPicture(Guid id)` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you call *.ToString()*.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPicture", "Home", new {id = Model.ID.ToString()})" alt="Member Picture" />
```